# Test Class ignoring my 2 different maps

Tags: apex, unit-test

I'm struggling to test a line of code within my test class below:

```
 public static void cloneRenewalOpportunity(Map<Id, Opportunity> mapNewOpps, Map<Id,Opportunity> mapOldOpps){
    try{
        List<Opportunity> lstOpp = new List<Opportunity>();
        Set<String> sAccountId = new Set<String>();
        Id ArchiveRT = Schema.SObjectType.Opportunity.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Archive').getRecordTypeId();
        system.debug('NEW MAP '+ mapNewOpps);
        system.debug('OLD MAP '+ mapOldOpps);
        for(Opportunity opp : mapNewOpps.values()){
            //if the opportunity is an Archive RT Opportunity then Clone 
            if(mapOldOpps.containsKey(opp.Id) && opp.RecordTypeId == ArchiveRT){
                Opportunity oldOpp = mapOldOpps.get(opp.Id);
                system.debug('new'+opp.name+''+opp.stagename);
                system.debug('old'+oldOpp.name+''+oldOpp.stagename);
                if(opp.StageName != oldOpp.StageName && opp.StageName == 'Closed Won'){
                    sAccountId.add(opp.AccountId);
                    lstOpp.add(opp);
                }
```

Mainly this line here:

```
if(opp.StageName != oldOpp.StageName && opp.StageName == 'Closed Won'){
```

in my test class I have created 4 test Opportunities with different names and stages however when i add them run the test class it only ever picks up the first Opportunity so will never hit that line in the apex class

```
RecordType rt = [SELECT Id, Name, DeveloperName FROM RecordType WHERE SObjectType = 'Opportunity' AND Name = 'Archive'];

 Opportunity oppr = new Opportunity(); 
    oppr.RecordTypeId = rt.Id;   
    oppr.Name = 'OPP 1';       
    oppr.StageName = 'Closed Won';
    oppr.Payment_Terms__c = '30 Days';
    insert oppr;

    Opportunity oppr2 = new Opportunity(); 
    oppr2.RecordTypeId = rt.Id;   
    oppr2.Name = 'Opp 2';   
    oppr2.Probability=20;      
    oppr2.StageName = 'Closed Won';
    oppr2.Payment_Terms__c = '30 Days';
    insert oppr2;

    Opportunity oppr3 = new Opportunity(); 
    oppr3.RecordTypeId = rt.Id;   
    oppr3.Name = 'Opp 3';   
    oppr3.Probability=20;      
    oppr3.StageName = 'Initial Discussion';
    oppr3.Payment_Terms__c = '30 Days';
    insert oppr3;

    Opportunity oppr4 = new Opportunity(); 
    oppr4.RecordTypeId = rt.Id;   
    oppr4.Name = 'Opp 4';   
    oppr4.StageName = 'Initial Discussion';
    oppr4.Payment_Terms__c = '30 Days';

    insert oppr4;

    Map<Id, Opportunity> mapOldOpps = new Map<Id, Opportunity>();
    Map<Id, Opportunity> mapNewOpps = new Map<Id, Opportunity>();

    mapNewOpps.put(Oppr3.id, Oppr3);
    mapNewOpps.put(Oppr4.id, Oppr4);
    mapOldOpps.put(Oppr3.Id, Oppr3);
    mapOldOpps.put(Oppr.Id, Oppr);
    mapOldOpps.put(Oppr2.id, Oppr2);

    // RenewalOpportunity ro = new RenewalOpportunity();
    List<Opportunity> LstOpp = new List<Opportunity>();

    RenewalOpportunity.cloneRenewalOpportunity(mapNewOpps, mapOldOpps);
```

Any help why it only ever picks the opp "Opp 1" would be massive help, Thanks

Comment: what is `rt.id` in `oppr.RecordTypeId = rt.Id;`. Make sure the record type of opportunity in test class is `Archive`.

Comment: you are passing uneven maps i.e. pass old map with old data and then add a new version of opportunities to the new map, I don't see you adding an updated opportunity ?

Comment: @Samir I have added the rt.id query above forgot to include it on this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

**Please update stageName accordingly**

```
 Opportunity oppr = new Opportunity();
    oppr.RecordTypeId = rt.Id;
    oppr.Name = 'OPP 1';
    oppr.StageName = 'Closed Won';
    oppr.Payment_Terms__c = '30 Days';
    insert oppr;

    Opportunity oppr2 = new Opportunity();
    oppr2.RecordTypeId = rt.Id;
    oppr2.Name = 'Opp 2';
    oppr2.Probability=20;
    oppr2.StageName = 'Closed Won';
    oppr2.Payment_Terms__c = '30 Days';
    insert oppr2;

    Opportunity oppr3 = new Opportunity();
    oppr3.RecordTypeId = rt.Id;
    oppr3.Name = 'Opp 3';
    oppr3.Probability=20;
    oppr3.StageName = 'Initial Discussion';
    oppr3.Payment_Terms__c = '30 Days';
    insert oppr3;

    Opportunity oppr4 = new Opportunity();
    oppr4.RecordTypeId = rt.Id;
    oppr4.Name = 'Opp 4';
    oppr4.StageName = 'Initial Discussion';
    oppr4.Payment_Terms__c = '30 Days';

    insert oppr4;

    Map<Id, Opportunity> mapOldOpps = new Map<Id, Opportunity>();
    Map<Id, Opportunity> mapNewOpps = new Map<Id, Opportunity>();

    mapOldOpps.put(Oppr3.Id, Oppr3);
    mapOldOpps.put(Oppr.Id, Oppr);
    mapOldOpps.put(Oppr2.id, Oppr2);
    mapOldOpps.put(Oppr1.id, Oppr1);

    //edit opportunities
    Opportunity updatedoppr = new Opportunity();
    updatedoppr.Id = oppr.Id;
    oppr.RecordTypeId = rt.Id;
    oppr.Name = 'OPP 1';
    oppr.StageName = 'changed stage name';
    oppr.Payment_Terms__c = '30 Days';


    Opportunity updatedoppr2 = new Opportunity();
    updatedoppr2.Id = oppr2.Id;
    oppr2.RecordTypeId = rt.Id;
    oppr2.Name = 'Opp 2';
    oppr2.Probability=20;
    oppr2.StageName = 'changed stage name';
    oppr2.Payment_Terms__c = '30 Days';

    Opportunity updatedoppr3 = new Opportunity();
    updatedoppr3.Id = oppr3.Id;
    oppr3.RecordTypeId = rt.Id;
    oppr3.Name = 'Opp 3';
    oppr3.Probability=20;
    oppr3.StageName = 'Ichanged stage name';
    oppr3.Payment_Terms__c = '30 Days';

    Opportunity updatedoppr4 = new Opportunity();
    updatedoppr4.Id = oppr4.Id;
    oppr4.RecordTypeId = rt.Id;
    oppr4.Name = 'Opp 4';
    oppr4.StageName = 'changed stage name';
    oppr4.Payment_Terms__c = '30 Days';

    mapNewOpps.put(updatedoppr.Id, updatedoppr);
    mapNewOpps.put(updatedoppr2.Id, updatedoppr2);
    mapNewOpps.put(updatedoppr3.id, updatedoppr3);
    mapNewOpps.put(updatedoppr3.id, updatedoppr4);

    // RenewalOpportunity ro = new RenewalOpportunity();
    List<Opportunity> LstOpp = new List<Opportunity>();

    RenewalOpportunity.cloneRenewalOpportunity(mapNewOpps, mapOldOpps);
```